# Why do I get empty dataframe after LazyClassifier?

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, model, classification

Given train data with x_train data frame and y_train data frame, I also have the test data frame and the actual classes. I want to use LazyClassifier to see which classifier will fit my data the best. When I insert my data into the fit method of the classifier I get an empty result. Here is what I have and what I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ur2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEgDd.png)

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code, data, or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Instead, please edit your question to include this information as text: which makes it much easier to copy-and-paste code, and makes content easier to search.

Answer (score 0):

Change   **ignore_warnings=False** to **ignore_warnings=True**

> `clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0,ignore_warnings=True, custom_metric=None)`

If you are getting an empty dataframe in return while running LazyClassifier it means that all the models are getting failed to execute and there can be different reasons. For example:

```
CategoricalNB model failed to execute Negative values in data passed
to CategoricalNB (input X)
```

or

```
NuSVC model failed to execute
specified nu is infeasible
```

Fixing them will require data preprocessing.